# How to give a name for a file?

Tags: python, numpy

For every iteration in my loop for, I need to give 'the number of my iteration' as a name for the file, for example, the goal is to save:

```
my first iteration in the first file.
my second iteration in the second file.
....
```

I use for that the library numpy, but my code doesn't give me the solution that i need, in fact my actual code oblige me to enter the name of the file after each iteration, that is easy if I have 6 or 7  iteration, but i am in the case that I have 100 iteration, it doesn't make sense:

```
for line, a in enumerate(Plaintxt_file):
    #instruction
    #result
    fileName = raw_input()
    if(fileName!='end'):
        fileName = r'C:\\Users\\My_resul\\Win_My_Scripts\\'+fileName
        np.save(fileName+'.npy',Result)
ser.close()
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: does your file names have a sequence to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your file name from the line number:

```
for line, a in enumerate(Plaintxt_file):
    fileName = r'C:\Users\My_resul\Win_My_Scripts\file_{}.npy'.format(line)
    np.save(fileName, Result)
```

This start with file name `file_0.npy`.
If you like to start with `1`, specify the starting index in `enumerate`:

```
for line, a in enumerate(Plaintxt_file, 1):
```

Of course, this assumes you don't need `line` starting with `0` anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what your issue is, but as far as I can tell, you just need some string formatting for the filename.

So, you want, say 100 files, each one created after an iteration.  The easiest way to do this would probably be to use something like the following:

```
for line, a in enumerate():
    #do work
    filename = "C:\\SaveDir\\OutputFile{0}.txt".format(line)
    np.save(filename, Result)
```

That won't be 100% accurate to your needs, but hopefully that will give you the idea.

Comment: @roganjosh I wasn't quite sure what line was supposed to be.  If it is the line number, then yes, you're right, you could get rid of i entirely.

Comment: @roganjosh We're not really given enough information to be able to say what it is.  It might be the string holding the text information from the given line that is to be saved.

Comment: @roganjosh Ah, yes, you're right.  Somehow I haven't run across the built-in enumerate before - I was assuming that it was a custom function.  I have updated my answer accordingly (at which point it is pretty much the same as Mike's).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after, say, 100 blank files with the naming scheme "0.npy", "1.npy", all the way up to "n-1.npy", a simple for loop would do the job (no need for numpy!):

```
n = 100
for i in range(n):
    open(str(i) + ".npy", 'a').close()
```

This loop runs for n iterations and spits out empty files with the filename corresponding to the current iteration

Comment: @roganjosh ugh too early in the morning haha

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the sequence of the files and you do not want the files from multiple runs of the loop to overwrite each other, you can use random [unique IDs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/uuid.html).

```
from uuid import uuid4
# ...    
for a in Plaintxt_file:
    fileName = 'C:\\Users\\My_resul\\Win_My_Scripts\\file_{}.npy'.format(uuid4())
    np.save(fileName, Result)
```

Sidenote:
Do not use *raw* strings and escaped backslashes together.
It's either `r"C:\path"` or `"C:\\path"` - unless you want double backslashes in the path. I do not know if Windows likes them.

Comment: I need  to keep  the sequence of my files  and I want to keep all the files that I will get because that is the most important thing in order to have an organised results.