# How to give my file a name composed of 4 parameters?

Tags: python, numpy

I already asked in this publication [How to give a name for a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796922/how-to-give-a-name-for-a-file/41800895#41800895) about how to give 'the number of my iteration' as a name for the file, I had a good answer, but now I need to give my file a name that composed of 4 parameters because that will help me to make an easy interpretation: 
This is my code:

```
for b in Key_file:
    key_16b=b[0:32]
    key128=binascii.unhexlify(key_16b)
Ciphertxt_file = open("C:\\Users\\user\\Win_My_Scripts\\Ciphertexts.txt", "w")
Plaintxt_file = open(r'C:\\Users\\user\\Win_My_Scripts\\Plaintexts.txt', 'r')
for line, a in enumerate(Plaintxt_file):
    plaintxt_16b=a[0:32]
    plaintext=binascii.unhexlify(plaintxt_16b)
    clear_msg=b'\x24'+b'\x73'+plaintext+b'\x74'+key128
    print('Trace number:', line)
    ser.write(clear_msg)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ciphertext= (ser.read(250))
    print(ciphertext)
    Ciphertxt_file.write(ciphertext)
    dataArray = get_data(['C2'],8000,scope)
    fileName =  r'C:\\Users\\user\\My_resul\\Win_My_Scripts\\file_{}.npy'.format(line) 
    np.save(fileName, dataArray)
ser.close()                # close ports
```

I need to name each file like this:

```
AES_iteration=number_of_iteration_key128=key128_Plaintext=Plaintext1_Ciphertext=ciphertext1
```

For example:

```
AES_iteration=1_key128=0c0d0e0f08090a0b0405060700010203_Plaintext=7a8e5dc390781eab8df2c090bf4bebca_Ciphertext=17CFCD13 784AECB0 204375E1 C58ECBC3
```

By this way, I will be sure that all my file are synchronized and that I have the best results.

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Read the documentation on "format".  See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting - section 6.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to format the filename another way:

```
fileName = (r'C:\\Users\\user\\My_resul\\Win_My_Scripts\\'
               'AES_iteration={}_key128={}_Plaintext={}_Ciphertext={}.npy'
               .format(iteration,key128,plaintext,ciphertext))
```

Where `iteration`, `key128`, `plaintext` and `ciphertext` are variables (you should define yourself) containing the parameters.

`.format` is called on a "formatting string" in the formatting string, the `{}` denote parameters that should be filled in. You fill these in with the parameters you feed to the `.format(..)` call.

Comment: TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str,    That gives me this error.

Comment: Well in that case one of your arguments is not a string, or it introduces escape characters. You should inspect them.